# Using XamlReader.Load fails with my implemented TriggerAction, but succeeds with built-in one

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

My app loads XAML dynamically - the XAML can come from my server and thus I cannot just instantiate a control.

I use XamlReader.Load() for this, and have been for a while now.

I am having issues of a curious nature right now - when I try to deserialize XAML that contains a reference to my trigger, the reader throws an exception saying it cannot parse the xaml:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred   Message=Unknown
>   parser error: Scanner 2147500037. [Line: 5 Position: 10]
>   LineNumber=5   LinePosition=10   StackTrace:
>          at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CreateFromXaml(String xamlString, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean requireDefaultNamespace, Boolean
>   allowEventHandlers, Boolean expandTemplatesDuringParse, Boolean
>   trimDeclaredEncoding)
>          at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(String xaml)
>          at LoadXamlFail.MainPage.myTrigger_Clicked(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Now, when I try to deserialize XAML that contains a reference to a Blend trigger, everything works just fine. Here's the XAML that contains the Blend trigger:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <eim:PlaySoundAction/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

And here's the XAML that contains my trigger:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <local:MyTrigger/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

My trigger is as simple as I could make it - it essentially does not do anything:

```
public class MyTrigger  : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    public MyTrigger()
    {
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
    }
}
```

The code that loads the XAML (same code for both cases - one works the other doesn't) looks like this:

```
using (var stream = App.GetResourceStream(new System.Uri("/LoadXamlFail;component/OtherTriggerControl.xaml", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var xaml = reader.ReadToEnd();
    xaml = FixXaml(xaml);
    XamlReader.Load(xaml);
}
```

Finally, loading the XAML by dropping the control that backs the XAML works just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this, or how to work around it?

(If someone wants to see a working example, download the code [here](https://www.box.com/s/jhmqzhdtrn7uxhqurk2g))

Comment: I'm getting an error message while accessing the sample: "The item you are trying to access has either been deleted or is unavailable to you"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out (and by figured it out, I mean somebody on a different forum gave me the answer).

Essentially, when using XamlReader, you cannot rely on the behavior of regular XAML where namespaces located inside your assembly do not need to be decorated with the assembly= element.

http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/xamlreader-and-xamlparseexception-occurred-messageunknown-parser-error-scanner-2147500037/

Comment: missing namespaces declarations... xmlns:local="clr-assembly ..."

Comment: Yeah, but with "normal" XAML, the one that gets loaded by default by the app, you don't need to specify the namespace for the default namespace (the namespace the assembly lives in). With XamlReader, you do.